# Use of IEnumerable<> and IFormFileCollection, in .NET 6 Minimal API

Tags: c#, ienumerable, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

Problem is, I have an API that concatenates pdfs from Urls, and it's working in .NET 5 , but when starting to migrate to .NET 6, the use of IEnumerable<> , IFormFile, and IFormFileCollection , simply only accepts requests application/json.

Here is the endpoint in .NET 5 (Working)

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConcatenarPdfsByUrl([FromForm] IEnumerable<string> urls)
        {
            var output = await TransformaPdfCore.PdfConcatenation(urls);
            return File(output, "application/octet-stream");
        }
```

result: [Imagem 1 (.net 5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Xz6.png)

And so is Endpoint in Minimal .net6

```
app.MapPost("/ConcatenaPdfsByUrl", async Task<IResult> (IEnumerable<string> urls, TransformaPdfCore transforma) =>
{
    {
        var output = await transforma.PdfConcatenation(urls);
        return Results.File(output, "application/octet-stream");
    }
}).Accepts<IEnumerable<string>>("multipart/form-data");
```

But the result is this: [Imagem 2 (.net 6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAXWr.png)

The question is, why does IEnumerable not have the same behavior? and if there is any solution, for example using IOperationFilter, so that I can make it work.

The IFormFileCollection Interface had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Currently binding from form is not supported for minimal APIs. You can track [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39430) on github - the support is investigated for .NET 7. You can try to implement custom binding from form via [`BindAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bindasync) method using `HttpContext.Request.Form` or just add `HttpContext` parameter to your handler method and use it there:

```
app.MapPost("/ConcatenaPdfsByUrl", async (HttpContext context, TransformaPdfCore transforma) =>
{
    // use context.Request.Form or context.Request.Form.Files
    var output = await transforma.PdfConcatenation(urls);
    return Results.File(output, "application/octet-stream");
})
```